# Angular Modulo for wrapping 3 items in iteration into a div

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, modulo

I'm currently trying to pack a wrapper div within 3 items of a `ngFor`:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="stories.length > 0" [ngIfElse]="empty">
    <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport [itemSize]="itemSize | async" (scrolledIndexChange)="nextBatch()">

        <ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let story of stories; let i = index; trackBy:trackById">
            <div class="inner-wrap" *ngIf="(i+1) % 3 !== 1">
                <app-story-preview class="fade-in-animation" [layout]="layout | async" [item]="story"></app-story-preview>
            </div>
        </ng-container>

    </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</ng-template>
```

I would have expected here that 3x `app-story-preview` will be packed into the`div.inner-wrap` ... But they won't. it always ends up 1x `app-story-preview` in the div ... Anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to transform your stories array to array of subarrays with 3 elements inside, for example

```
let array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
let size = 3;
let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i <Math.ceil(array.length/size); i++){
    result[i] = array.slice((i*size), (i*size) + size);
}
```

and use it like this

```
<ng-container *cdkVirtualFor="let storyBlock of stories; let i = index;">
                <div class="inner-wrap" *ngFor="let story of storyBlock">
                    <app-story-preview class="fade-in-animation" [layout]="layout | async" [item]="story"></app-story-preview>
                </div>
</ng-container>
```